# Preference setting for being notified of unanswered questions

Tags: feature-request, notifications

I happen to just look at my profile page and check the questions I have asked in the past. I usually try to do this every so often to make sure I don't leave any questions I have asked with no marked answer. I noticed I had a few from earlier in the year that I plan forgot about.

This may be for those more dedicated DBA.SE users that don't like to leave open questions (like me). Is it possible for some kind of notification to be setup for like "hey did you know you have questions with no answer marked"?

Or is there some other option that is available for being notified of this that I am not aware of?

Comment: JNK's search solution is the best way to go with the system as it is. If you feel strongly that that doesn't work for you, you can try a feature request on [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) and see what the community thinks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use some of the advanced search options for this.  Run a search for:

`user:me hasaccepted:no`